# C++ syntax question, use of the class keyword

Tags: c++

Can any one explain "class X x;" what actually it mean ...in the program...Please give me some example also?
Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
    public:
        X() {}
};

class Y {
    public:
        Y() {}
};

int main()
 {
    class X x; //what is this? explain it
    class Y y; //what is this? explain it
    class Z z; //what is this? explain it    //error
    return 0;
  }
```

Edited: May i know the exact difference between "Class Z z" and "Z z".Because While 
compiling this program in 2 ways

```
  class Z Z;   //here iam getting as Error: error: incomplete type is not allowed
  Z z; //error: identifier "Z" is undefined
```

Since iam asking the exact difference.

Comment: please...comment ...while ur giving the negative rating..Since Give me a chance to know ..where i did the mistake?

Comment: Those instructions just define 3 variables. The `class` keyword is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK

```
class X x;
```

is equivalent to

```
X x;
```

(*EDIT: for those nitpickers: at least, in your case, when X is a previously defined class and there is no other variable named X in the same scope*).

In plain-old C, whenever you define a `struct` without a `typedef`, you have explicitly use the `struct` keyword when creating variables. In C++, one can omit the `struct` keyword, but you also can write `struct X x;` if you prefer that. And since the only difference between `class` and `struct` in C++ is the default visibility, one can conclude that it is also legal to write  `class X x;`

**Answer to your edit:**

```
 class Z;
```

is a forward declaration (often used in header files where you don't want to `#include "Z.hpp"`). This is also called an *incomplete type declaration*. It allows *pointers* to Z to be declared, for example

```
 class Z *z;
```

is legal code, even when the compiler has not seen any class body declaration of Z. What is not allowed is to create an instance of z like `class Z z;` as long as Z is incomplete from the compiler's view.

The code `Z z;`, however cannot be interpreted as a forward declaration by the compiler (not even as a disallowed forward declaration). It just shows up as "Z is undefined".

Comment: If you look at your code, you've only defined the types for classes `X` and `Y`. You get a different error with and without the `class` keyword because the compiler is able to infer more of your code and give you a more accurate error. When it simply sees `Z z;`, it's not sure what `Z` was supposed to be at all. When it sees `class Z z;`, it knows that `Z` should be a class, and since it's not defined, it's able to give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: @sharth:I think BE is asking that as a doubt.X,Y are declared.Z is not declared.Then Be asking the difference between "class Z z;" ,"Z z".Is this is your doubt BE

Comment: @USER :Yeah You are right BE.Iam totally confusing regarding this

Comment: @Doc Brown:I agree with your answer .But while... "class Z z;" //here:error it shows as incomplete....where as "Z z;"here error it shows as unidentified z.. may i know the exact difference and full details

Comment: @Doc Brown:Thanks For your valuable answer

Comment: Sorry, `class X x` is not equivalent to `X x`. If this would not be an accepted answer, I would not downvote. See @Chubsdad's answer.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: nitty, nitty. I did not meant "equivalent" in all cases, but only in context of the question, there's no variable named X in that case. But I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This is called an elborated type specifier and is useful in cases such as below:

> $9.1/3 - "An elaborated-type-specifier
>   (7.1.5.3) can also be used as a
>   type-specifier as part of a
>   declaration. It differs from a class
>   declaration in that if a class of the
>   elaborated name is in scope the
>   elaborated name will refer to it."

```
int bad;

class bad{};

int main(){
   //bad b;
   class bad b;    // Elaborated type specifier
}
```

You should now be able to undersand the difference between `class Z z` and `Z z`;

Answer (score 3):

C++ started out as an extension of C.

In C class names are not full-fledged typenames. So in C, if you write

```
struct Blah
{
    int x;
};
```

then to declare a variable of this class, in C you have to write

```
struct Blah myBlahObject;
```

In C++ the class name is a full-fledge typename, so you can just write

```
Blah myBlahObject;
```

But mainly for compatibility with C, C++ retains the C-style declaration syntax, and generalizes it to also work with the C++ `class` keyword.

And that means that in C++ you *can* write e.g.

```
class NeverSeenBefore* p;
```

to declare a pointer variable `p` of type `NeverSeenBefore*`. Where `NeverSeenBefore` has not been declared anywhere yet. It's just an *incomplete type*, and use of the `class` (or `struct`) keyword informs the compiler, as in C, that there is such a type, even though it's not yet been declared.

C++ has a built in incomplete type, called `void`  --  and you get the same kind of error message (from a good compiler) if you try to declare a `void` variable.

The main difference between `void` and other incomplete types is that `void` can not be completed.

By the way, the C technique for obtaining a full fledged typename is to use `typedef`. Since class names are full fledged typenames in C++, such `typedef` is not necessary in C++. So, when you see C++ code where a `typedef` is provided for a class *instead* of just naming the class, then you know that a C programmer has been there  – or a person taught by a C programmer (or recursively, taught by a person taught by a C programmer, so on).

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

`class X x;` instantiates an object of type `class X` on the stack that is named `x`. Looking at your definition of `X` there are no methods or fields, so you really can't do much with it.

Do you know what classes are in c++?

Answer (score 0):

When declaring an instance of a class, the `class` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0):

As per your new edit,

`class Z z;` when the compiler encounter this, it identifies that `Z` is a class since you specified it. But it cannot find the declaration of the `class Z`. Hence it is showing `error: incomplete type is not allowed`.

Now, when the compiler encounters `Z z;` it will not have any idea about what `Z` is since you didn't specify it anywhere. So it reports `error: identifier "Z" is undefined`.